# Angular ngResources request interceptor

Tags: angularjs, request, ngresource

Why angular $resources not have a request and request error interceptor?

Theres any way to do that?

Doc content:

interceptor - {Object=} - The interceptor object has two optional methods - response and responseError. Both response and responseError interceptors get called with http response object. See $http interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own interceptors as follows.

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
});

app.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            // insert code to populate your request header for instance
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                // insert code to redirect to custom unauthorized page
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: But this works just with Http requests made with $http

Comment: No, this works with $resource too. $resource wraps $http for use in RESTful web API scenarios.